# Convert a string of integers represented in different formats into a list of integers Python

Tags: python

Is there an easy way, apart from looping, to convert this kind of representation to a list of integers?

```
s = ['0','1','2:5','0x4']
```

to

```
list_i=[0,1,2,3,4,5,0,0,0,0]
```

Comment: You are wrong assuming that `'0x4'` is `[0, 0, 0, 0]`. In fact it is `4`.

Comment: You *will* have to loop in some form or another, a list isn't going to transform as a whole.

Comment: `0x4` is a hexadecimal that indicates `4` in decimal numbers

Comment: @Lutz, Benyamin: I'm pretty sure OP wants "0x4" *to mean* "four times the number 0". Same as they want "2:5" to mean the range from 2 to 5.

Comment: @deceze Of course he/she/it does. Anyway, let's close this question as being unclear.

Comment: @Lutz I think the question is rather clear. It's just pretty lazy.

Comment: @deceze Well, there is no close reason for being lazy.

Comment: I have a string that is like that. And that is why I gave an example of what it would expand to. Could you explain how it is lazy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension with the ternary operator like this:

```
list_i = [i for t in s for i in ((lambda r: range(int(r[0]), int(r[1]) + 1))(t.split(':')) if ':' in t else (lambda r: [int(r[0])] * int(r[1]))(t.split('x')) if 'x' in t else (int(t),))]
```

or you can use a `for` loop instead:

```
list_i = []
for token in s:
    if ':' in token:
        start, end = token.split(':')
        list_i.extend(list(range(int(start), int(end) + 1)))
    elif 'x' in token:
        number, repeat = token.split('x')
        list_i.extend([int(number)] * int(repeat))
    else:
        list_i.append(int(token))
```

Comment: I would not want to maintain this monstrosity.

Comment: Posted the list comprehension solution first while continuing to work on a loop version.

Comment: Thank you for your reply

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't. You need to handle the special strings seperately. You need to loop through the list, check if the given element is a simple integer, if so, convert it as it is. If the element being considered is special (`0x4` or `2:5` in your case), you need code to handle it. Try this:

```
oldList = ['0','1','2:5','0x4'] 

def isInt(val):
    try:
        int(val)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

def convertRange(val):
    l = val.split(':')
    return [x for x in range(int(l[0]), int(l[1])+1)]


def convertRepetition(val):
    l = val.split('x')
    return [int(l[0]) for i in range(0, int(l[1]))]

newList = []

for elem in oldList:
    if ':' in elem:
        newList.extend(convertRange(elem))

    elif 'x' in elem:
        newList.extend(convertRepetition(elem))

    elif isInt(elem):
        newList.append(int(elem))

print(newList)
```

the `convertRange()` and `convertRepitition()` functions take care of the two special cases your question mentions.

Comment: Thank you for you reply. I did use something like this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the freedom to redefine how the s-list is set, you can use python syntax like this

```
s = ['[0]','[1]','range(2,6)','[0]*4'] 
list_i = []
[exec('list_i+='+i) for i in s]
print(list_i)
# which outputs
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But unfortunately I don't have the freedom to redefine the s-list